Is Kepler's Supernova a double degenerate or single degenerate supernova?
I know that SN 1604 is a Type Ia supernova. But was it formed from two white dwarfs colliding in a double degenerate scenario, or in a single white dwarf accreting matter? I have seen supporters of both theories.

can you show and link where you have seen support for either hypothesis?

Note that double-degenerate also results from a white-dwarf accreting matter-- it's just accreting from a white-dwarf companion.  It's unlikely to be an actual collision.

As posed, this question would appear to be seeking an opinion.

There is no consensus on this issue for any of the Type Ia supernovae.
